# Converting $5\log$ reduction to a percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I see a lot of terms bounded about like a 5log reduction of bacteria. So I presume it's $5\log_{10}$. Now how do I convert that into a percentage?

Would it be:

$$\begin{align}
5\log_{10}10=&\displaystyle \left(1-\dfrac{x}{100}\right)100\\
\Rightarrow x\%=&\displaystyle 100\left(1-\dfrac{1}{100}5\log_{10}10\right)
\end{align}$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $\log_{10}$ is reduced by $5$, the quantity is reduced by a factor $10^{-5}$.  This is $0.001\%$ of the original quantity, or a $99.999\%$ reduction

Comment: Thank you. can you put that in an equation format please?

Comment: @user1134241:  I'm not sure what you are looking for.  Maybe $\log_{10}(new)-\log_{10}(old)=-5 \implies \frac{new}{old}=10^{-5}$

Comment: Looks good, thank you. I was after something like a conversion formula between % and log so eg: What log reduction (x) is 55%. $x=-log(1-\dfrac{55}{100})\quad \Rightarrow\quad x\simeq0.347$?

Comment: @user1134241:  You have understood it correctly.  You have said $55\%$ is a reduction of $55\%$ or to $45\%$ of the original amount.  Various people use percentages in different ways.